# Como se puede obtner array de tabla y manipularlo con Jquery

Tags: json

Tengo la siguiente funcion fuera del ready:

```
 function dameCheques(){

     return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/procesocheque.php",
            data: { "accion":"listarc"}, 
      dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");

            },
            success:function(data){

            },
            });    

    };
```

Probe crear una variable global "cheque" y asignarle el resultado de la funcion, pero no logro leer el JSON. Tambien probe parsear en otra linea y da error. lo que obtengo viene de un script php donde hago un

```php
echo json_encode($array);
```

[image: Como veran es un objeto aparentemente pero no puedo ni parsearlo.]

No sera que debo usar GET en vez de POST en la peticion.. Dado que get es para obtener datos?

Osea no quiero ejecutar el pedido cada vez que necesito algo relacionado a los cheques.. Sino una sola vez.

Comment: Como es el formato del array que PHP esta devolviendo? me extarña la respuesta que te esta mostrando ya que lo haces con un json_enconde($array)

Comment: La función $.ajax es asincronica, quiere decir que con ese tipo de asignación no vas a obtener el resultado del json, ya que eso ocurre un tiempo despues, dentro del bloque success, te recomiendo que crees una variable y dentro de ese bloque lo asignes

Comment: Toda la razon @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas no habia visto ese codigo, ya no importa mucho mi pregunta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var datoCheques = null;

function dameCheques(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/procesocheque.php",
        data: { "accion":"listarc"}, 
        dataType:"json",

        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
            datoCheques = null;
        },
        success:function(data){
            datoCheques = data;
        },
    });
};
```

Ya con esto donde quiera que accedas a datoCheques puedes preguntar si es diferente de null,
y de esa manera vas a saber que tiene valor y es el traido por la petición de ajax

Comment: Luego debo llamar a dameCheques() dentro del ready? Porque no me funciono me devuelve nulo en la consola.La funcion esta fuera del ready.